# Do I need to rebuild my entire database for a single change with migrations

Tags: laravel, migration

I am confused about the practical use of migrations in Laravel; please help me get some clarity.

Let's say I have all my tables set up with create_blabla_table.php migrations and now I decided that the company table does not only need a name but also a slug column.

SO. I go the create_companies_table.php and edit it: I add the string field slug.

How does this change get through? Do I now need to reset my entire database and re-seed all tables? Or can I update this single table?

Or should I create a new migration file like add_company_slug_field.php. But then I am going to have  a LOT of migration files, and I might lose track of it.

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways actually .. first is to

`php artisan migrate:rollback`

then updating your migrate files .. before re-running

`php artisan migrate`

but that would clear all records already saved in your database ..

if you dont want that another way is to create a new migration with

**UPDATE A COLUMN ATTRIBUTE**

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable()->change();
});
```

**RENAMING A COLUMN**

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

**DROPPING A COLUMN**

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn(['votes', 'avatar', 'location']);
});
```

**NEW COLUMN**

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email');
});
```

> then there's a shortcut but ***not a good practice*** .. update your migration files .. then manually updating the database ..

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to generate a new migration that modifies the table the way you want and then run **php artisan migrate**

Comment: So I might need a new migration with an alter table statement?

Comment: Yes you can do this and then you will not need rollback

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed column in your migration you should follow two steps

1. Rollback
2. Migrate

When you run command `php artisan migrate:rollback` whole migrations will be rolled back and when you run `php artisan migrate` all migrations will be migrated in default case and you should run seeders.

If you have independent table with no foreign key constraints then, You can perform single table migration by incrementing table batch number in migration table. After changing batch number just rollback and migrate your table using artisan commands.

For the tables with foreign key, parent should be created before child some time error may occur due to wrong order in migration.

You can make rollback/migrate operation for group of tables as well by incrementing batch value.

In this way you can change specific table.